# Treeview in MVC using MongoDB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, treeview

Has anyone had success building a treeview like structure in MVC with data from MongoDB? Resources on the web seem to be minimal. I am trying to have each collection in the database have a node, and the document/documents within the collection to be child nodes.